# How to plot a histogram with different colors by group and facet grid in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"group":   ["aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb"],
                     "segment": ["da", "et", "da", "et", "da", "et", "da", "et"],
                     "country": ["br", "br", "th", "th", "br", "br", "th", "th"],
                     "N":       [31, 23, 17, 9, 4, 100, 10, 20],
                     "totalN":  [84, 84, 389, 389, 84, 84, 389, 389]}
                    )
```

I would like to the same plot in **python** like the one that is produced by the following **R** code

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=segment, y=N, fill=group)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
ggtitle("group") +
facet_grid(country~.)+
geom_text(aes(label=percent(round(N / totalN, 2))), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=3) +
coord_flip()
```

I have tried

```
data_groupped = data.groupby(['group', 'segment'])
data_groupped.plot(x='segment', y='N', kind='hist')
```

It produces every histogram separately.

So the expected output is like this:

[image]

Comment: when you use the plt.hist command, you get a list of values, a list of bin edges, and list of patches.  assign each segment a unique number (you can change tick labels later), and create a histogram for each group (aa, bb), then you can position the patches of n+1 by looking at where the top of patch n goes

Comment: Include your include lines -- I assume you're using Pandas but it isn't a [MVCE] until it's explicit.

Comment: In Pandas, there's a `stacked` argument to `hist()`. See the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/visualization.html#histograms).

Comment: @cphlewis editted ! thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Using pandas plots, you could do

**Option 1]** Use `pivot_table` to reshape data of the `groups`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

groups = data.groupby('country')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(groups.ngroups,sharex=True)
for (g, grp), ax in zip(groups, axes.flatten()):
    grp_df = grp.pivot_table(index='segment', columns='group', values='N', aggfunc=np.sum)
    grp_df.plot.barh(stacked=True, ax=ax, sharex=True)
```

[image]

---

**Option 2]** Reshape the data first into `df`, and then use `plot`

```
df = (data.groupby('country')
        .apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['segment', 'group'])['N'].sum().unstack())
        .unstack(level=0)
        .reorder_levels((1,0), axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
)
cgroups = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(cgroups.ngroups, sharex=True)
for (c, grp), ax in zip(cgroups, axes.flatten()):
    sp = grp[c].plot.barh(stacked=True, ax=ax, sharex=True)
```

[image]

```
df
```

[image]

---

**Option 3]** If you don't need separation of subplots

```
df = (data.groupby('country')
        .apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['segment', 'group'])['N'].sum().unstack()))
df.plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

[image]

```
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way using the `option 1` to have a single legend ? Because now the legend is repeated at each plot. Also how could i add the value labels ?